# Can I use the python 'socket' module for listening on my external ip? if no, is there a preinstalled module which can?

Tags: python-3.x, ip-address

I have built a small program that listens to a port on my laptop and an other program on my phone that connects to that port on my laptop. Now this all works fine but i was wondering if that same module could be used with external ip adresses. If it doesn't work with external ip's, is there a preinstalled module that can work with external ip's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you forward that port in your network bridge (probably your all-in-one router) then yes! Simply listen on IPv4 address `0.0.0.0` or IPv6 address `::` (maybe `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0%0`) to ensure that you're listening on all available IP addresses, instead of just `localhost`, and you're good to go.

Comment: How can I forward my port? And then I should be able to connect from a different network to the external ip from my computer?

Comment: @Seppukki That depends on your router. What router do you have?

Comment: TP-link i think, but i have no access to the online interface of my router

Comment: @Seppukki Well, this is the wrong site for help with that!